# How to fail a systemd service if an error is raised from python script it is running?

Tags: python-3.x, systemd

I am running a python script as daemon service using systemd, at times, I have set up to code to raise an exception in certain situations. However that does not fail my systemd service , it continues to show `Status: running(active)` which is missleading.

this is my systemd service unit:

```
[Unit]
Description=Internet Speed test service.
After=multi-user.target
Wants=network-online.target
After=network-online.target
After=mariadb.service


[Service]
Type=idle
Restart=always
RestartSec=10s
TimeoutStopSec=5
EnvironmentFile=/lib/systemd/system/home_iot.env
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /usr/local/iot/home_iot/internet_speed_monitor.py
SendSIGKILL=no
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

and this is the python script:

```
"""Perform internet speed test.
"""
import os
import re
import logging
import subprocess
import shlex
import socket
import time
import getpass
from pprint import pprint
from threading import Timer

# Internal imports
from home_iot import core as _core


logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
_log = logging.getLogger(__name__)


def command_exists(command):
    """Check if command exists or not.
    
    Args:
        command (str) : command to run installed in /bin folder.
    """
    rc = subprocess.call(shlex.split(command))
    if rc == 0:
        return True
    return False

def _execute_command(command):
    if not command_exists(command):
        raise ValueError("Command {} not found.".format(command.split()[-1]))
    ps = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    response = ps.stdout.read()
    return response.strip().decode('utf-8')


def check_internet_speed():
    """Performs internet speed test.

    Returns:
        (dict) : speed test data.
    """
    cmd = _execute_command("which speedtest-cli")
    _log.info("Command to run: {0} for {1}".format(cmd, getpass.getuser()))
    resp = _execute_command("{cmd} --simple --bytes --secure".format(cmd=cmd))
    ping = re.findall('Ping:\s(.*?)\s', resp, re.MULTILINE)
    download = re.findall('Download:\s(.*?)\s', resp, re.MULTILINE)
    upload = re.findall('Upload:\s(.*?)\s', resp, re.MULTILINE)
    return {
    "ping": float(ping[0]), 
    "download": float(download[0]), 
    "upload": float(upload[0])
    }


def _store_record(data):
    """Stores internet speed test data to db.

    Arguments:
        data (dict) : internet speed test record.
    """
    table_name = "{0}_internet_speed_test".format(socket.gethostname())
    if all(data.values()):
        with _connect(db="internet_records") as conn:
            if not conn:
                _log.error("Failed to connect to database engine.")
                return
            _core.insert_row(data, table_name, conn)
    else:
        _log.error("All results not recived.")


def main(dryrun=False, mins=60):
    """Run the internet speed test and update the record in db.

    Keyword Args:
        dryrun (bool) : prints to terminal and does not update 
        record if True else update record and does not print to terminal.
        mins (int) : interval after which the speed test to run again.
    """
    roku_status = None
    if dryrun:
        data = check_internet_speed()
        pprint(data)
        return dryrun
    else:
        data = check_internet_speed()
        _store_record(data)
        Timer(mins*30, main).start()

@contextlib.contextmanager
def _connect(db=None):
    if db:
        _CFG["database"] = db
    connection = None
    try:
        _log.debug("{usr} connecting to {db} on {host}.".format(
            usr=_CFG["user"],
            db=_CFG["database"],
            host=_CFG["host"]
            )
        )
        connection = mysql.connector.connect(**_CFG)
    except mysql.connector.Error as err:
        if err.errno == errorcode.ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR:
            _log.error("Something is wrong with your user name or password")
        elif err.errno == errorcode.ER_BAD_DB_ERROR:
            _log.error("Database does not exist")
        else:
            raise RuntimeError("{0}, Failed to connect to mariadb.".format(err))
    else:
        yield connection
```

what I want for any exception that happens in _connect function except block:

```
except mysql.connector.Error as err:
```

I want systemd to fail.